# After updating TYPO3, PHP and FLUX: Content Element with uid "XXXX" and type "flux_XXXXX" has no rendering definition

Tags: typo3, flux, typo3-8.x

I am currently supporting a friend by upgrading his TYPO3 Installation which is running FLUX 8.2.1, TYPO3 8.7.23 and PHP 7.1. We've no upgraded to 8.7.32, FLUX 9.5.0 and PHP 7.4.
After Upgrading we are now getting

```
FLUX: Content Element with uid "XXXX" and type "flux_XXXXX" has no rendering definition!
```

Errors in Front- and Backend.

This is my first FLUX Installation and I couldn't figure out what's the Problem. Any Hint is very appreciated.

***Addendum:***

I don't know if that makes any, but using Template Analysis, I found the following difference:

FLUX 8.2.1:

```
1593: #############################################
1594: ## TypoScript added by extension "Flux"
1595: #############################################
1596: 
1597: 
1598: # Setting Flux plugin TypoScript
1599: tt_content.flux_swiper =< lib.contentElement
1600: tt_content.flux_swiper {
1601:     templateName = Generic
1602:     20 = USER
1603:     20 {
1604:         userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
1605:         extensionName = Flux
1606:         pluginName = Swiper
1607:       vendorName = FluidTYPO3
1608:     }
1609: }
```

FLUX 9.5.0:

```
1526: #############################################
1527: ## TypoScript added by extension "ExtensionName"
1528: #############################################
1529: 
1530: 
1531: # Setting ExtensionName plugin TypoScript
1532: tt_content.extensionname_swiper =< lib.contentElement
1533: tt_content.extensionname_swiper {
1534:     templateName = Generic
1535:     20 = USER
1536:     20 {
1537:         userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
1538:         extensionName = ExtensionName
1539:         pluginName = Swiper
1540:     }
1541: }
```

Both seems to be auto generated, but the old typoscript is using flux as extension name and the new one the kickstarter extension name of the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the static_template is missing or you are not using the fluid_styled_content static template under your Template module or both. Check if the static templates are included.

What basically this means is that TYPO3 tries to render the content element but it can not find the TypoScript configuration to figure out how to render it.

Comment: Do you know if the Method changed from FLUX 8.2.1 to FLUX 9.5.0?

Comment: not really sure, i have never worked with FLUX but your problem has to do with a global issue that every extension with content elements has if the TypoScript is missing